# Android View Nullpointer (custom function in class)

Tags: android, view, nullpointerexception

So I'm trying to create a function within a class that inflates an XML.  The idea behind the function is to randomize some aspects of the UI, and each time the randomized image is clicked, it scrambles it again (so it calls itself after setting the image in an onClickListener).

Anyways, the big problem I'm having is that I'm relatively new to Android programming, and I'm trying to use getView() instead of a solid View.  I'm getting a null value instead.  I'm hoping this is just a quick fix of me not knowing any better.

```
public class Practice extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.practice_write, container, false);

    function();

    return view;
}

public void function(){

    final ImageView table1Row2Col1 = (ImageView) getView()
            .findViewById(R.id.table1Row2Col1);
    table1Row2Col1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            function();
        }
    });
```

This is obviously just a short sample, but the error I'm getting is the nullpointer exception with the line I'm using getView().  If someone could help me out, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getView() method will be return null in onCreateView cycle. try to use findViewById method from your inflated view instead of getView() method.

```
public class Practice extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.practice_write, container, false);

    function(view);

    return view;
}

public void function(View view){

    final ImageView table1Row2Col1 = (ImageView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.table1Row2Col1);
    table1Row2Col1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            function();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly.  View has to be a final variable though because it is called again on the onClick function.